# How to get logs of crashes when system wont response

Tags: windows-10, administrator, safe-mode, virus-removal

I got very strange thing happening all of sudden. My windows wont let me do

1. right click
2. Cltr alt del
3. Click on taskbar
4. Let me choose a icon
5. Let me run antivurus

It all started one day out of no where. Now all I see is blank desktop. 
In this situation what can i do to fibd logs or check my work in SVN and get what I can.
Basically I want to find logs more important to know reason and do a scan if possible

Comment: Did you try to boot into safe mode?

Comment: Did you install SVN software recently. It may be SVN overlays problem. Which SVN software are you using? Or try login with other user. check you have same problem.

Comment: @TechieGossip No, I didn't. The problem started coming after I left my seat and while It was locked screen

Comment: @Seth I couldn't as I wasn't able to log In.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the logs would be a secondary concern for me:

- first, I'd be looking to see whether I have a hardware problem. That means using a Live Windows boot disc or Live Linux boot disc of some sort to see whether the problem still manifests itself there
- then, I'd be looking at a Live Operating System (often Windows PE or Linux based) which you can boot from (via USB flash drive or DVD disc) in order to scan the system for malware or security threats without running anything on the hard drive. They will also allow you to recover any data/logs that currently can't answer
- obviously, another option is booting to 'Safe or Recovery Mode' but I've found a lot of the time the environment is too limited to properly allow me to do enough analysis to track things down in some cases. Hence, my recommendation for a Live Operating System which can you boot from. Of course, you can also try something like EndItAll which should shut down all non-essential programs and executables to see whether it's a rogue program as well...
  http://www.docsdownloads.com/enditall-1.htm
- if all else fails image the drive or physically remove the drive and place it in another computer (or a drive enclosure) and examine the logs from another system (possibly from within a Virtual Machine of some sort). Obviously, there are issues here if there is some sort of malware involved. You need to take precautions on the second computer in order to stop it being infected if it is something that is 'more automated'

Comment: After an hour long, I am in. While I am in and can do things which take a lot of time. I need to get logs and what not to find what happened, as I can see I am very limited to what I can do e.g I have to try to run Event Viewer as an admin for 10 minutes but still I see Action dialog box. I.T guy would take it away for the format but I need to know what caused it.