# Windows icons name disappeared and painfully slow

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, event-viewer

In my previous post, about [How to get logs of crashes when the system won't response](https://superuser.com/questions/1216789/how-to-get-logs-of-crashes-when-system-wont-response), My system is acting strangely. This morning I had a startup message saying about power too low and then I did f1 to restart it start too slow and when I log in. It says deleting 2 files from programs. I am unable to do anything for 16-20 min. During which everything is blank and when icon appear they don't have name (not even windows explorer icons)
I ran antivirus but nothing came up.

If antivirus came clean, I am suspecting it isn't a virus. What else should I look for and her info or fix the unknown problem?

What kind of error or warning should I look for?

Comment: Boot up in safe mode and from an elevated command prompt type in `SCF /SCANNOW`, reboot and see if that resolve or else post the cbs.log detail for people to see. Additionally look for odd services in services.msc and stop and disable, look over task manager processes running in memory from details tab and kill odd looking processes, and also check task scheduler for odd scheduled tasks, end and disable those. Do an [Offline AV Full Scan](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17466/windows-defender-offline-help-protect-my-pc) just to be thorough. and run MalwareBytes full scan too.

Comment: When you run `SCF /SCANNOW` in safe mode from elevated cmd prompt press Enter and let that run until it gives you a message and then do the reboot, check, and post the cbs.log as indicated in the cmd window once that completes. When it starts bogging down, try to already have task manager or resource monitor open and see if the disk, CPU, memory, etc. is high utilization wise and report back your findings. These should be good starting points so I would not delay and get going on the correlated tasks.

Comment: @McDonald's I don't have admin access and safe mode needs to log in.

Comment: You'll probably need to gain admin access then somehow so ask those that are the machine admins or the ones that set it up for an admin account credential or to make your account local admin on a temp basis, or else try to enable the local administrator account and set a password on it or else follow the instructions here to forcefully complete this task with a boot tool: https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password/1018192#1018192. Once you get admin access and can perform what I suggested, report back your results, etc.

Comment: @McDonald's what is cbs.log and where I will find it?

Comment: The CBS.log file is located in the `%windir%\Logs\CBS` folder and it is part of the log file that the SFC [System File Checker] logs it's operations, errors, and so forth to. So once the `SFC /SCANNOW` process completes (successfully or unsuccessfully) this is the text log file to look in for verbose detail of the operations with time stamps, etc.

Comment: @McDonald's I am in windows now. While I am in it. Can I find logs or SCF logs as admin refuses to log me in as admin in safe mode?

Comment: One another thing I noticed was when the problem occurs after rebooting and logging in, I see a delete dialog box, saying deleting 2 files from programs.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't include IT support and networks for corporate, I merely said that I cannot log in as I am not the admin. My question is genuine and needs to resume.

Comment: @Nofel "As it is system of office, I cannot log in my safe mode. " Ask you systems administrator for help.

Comment: @DavidPostill I removed the cooperate reference. Though the question is for my knowledge be it applied anywhere, cooperate sector or private.